# How to use the marathon healthChecks?

Tags: marathon

I execute `git clone https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon.git` to download the latest marathon,And I had known from marathon doc that we can set the property of 'healthChecks' to Monitor the job.

but when i start marathon , i can't find the property  'healthChecks' anywhere,

And i am sure that the marathon i had download is the latest.

anybody could tell me how to use the 'healthChecks' ?

this is the marathon doc for 'healthChecks'

And you can see it on  http://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#post-v2-apps

```
 "healthChecks": [
    {
        "protocol": "HTTP",
        "path": "/health",
        "gracePeriodSeconds": 3,
        "intervalSeconds": 10,
        "portIndex": 0,
        "timeoutSeconds": 10,
        "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3
    },
    {
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "gracePeriodSeconds": 3,
        "intervalSeconds": 5,
        "portIndex": 1,
        "timeoutSeconds": 5,
        "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3
    },
    {
        "protocol": "COMMAND",
        "command": { "value": "curl -f -X GET http://$HOST:$PORT0/health" },
        "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3
    }
],
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Health Checks doc](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/health-checks.html) page provides detailed information on how to use them.

[image: Screen shot of Health Checks in Marathon 0.11]

Note that health checks are application dependent, which means *you* have to implement them in your app and expose them since only you know what constitutes a healthy state in your app.

For example, Marathon itself has the [/ping](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#get-ping) URL which indicates a basic availability of the service.

Comment: but where to use them ? .   where is the property 'healthcheck' on marathon UI?????

Comment: I took a screen shot from Marathon 0.11 here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10436738/screenshots/2015-09-21_marathon_healthchecks.png and updated answer. Don't forget to vote/check the answer as correct, so that others also benefit from it.

Comment: which version did you used  ?   i download many different version of marathon,   but  I was unable to find where to configure the health check

Comment: As I said above in my comment, version 0.11 ... also, you need to implement them in your app. Unsure what's unclear?

Comment: sorry ,  I am hard to understand that,    you said 'you need to implement them in your app'  ?      does this mean that  I should  create  something like controller or servlet  in my app to tell marathon wheather my app is healthy  ?..    i am so sorry  ,   i'm not good at English......

Comment: Correct, @KingOfSocket you need to implement an endpoint in your app, say `/health` for example, with the logic capturing what makes your app healthy. For example, health could mean: all connections or databases are alive and available.

Comment: one more question ....  how could i do to configure the path which marathon to request to get my-App's information ,  you said `/health`  ?        I guess marathon use `http://${HOST}:${PORT}/${WEB_NAME}/health` to get My-App's health information ,  but how could marathon know the ${HOST} and ${PORT} ?...

Comment: StackOverflow is not a chat platform. If you want to discuss above questions, I suggest you go to the #mesos or #marathon channel on IRC/Freenode or join us on Slack at chat.mesosphere.com to continue.

Comment: OMG.  Leave people who are learning alone.  Stop ruining Stack Overflow with your definition of what it is and isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Editing of health checks is not available in the web interface prior to version v0.13.0, see [release notes](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/releases/tag/v0.13.0):

> Improved application modal
>   The application create/edit modal has undergone significant architectural and UX improvements.
>   It is now possible to specify application labels, accepted resource roles, the user field and
>   **health checks**. Additionally, a more fine-grained input validation and error handling has been
>   implemented.

On lower versions you should use the [Marathon REST API](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html)